# Santa Cruz Chameleon tire and wheel choice

Tags: tire, wheels

I’m thinking about upgrading to a Santa Cruz Chameleon. The majority of the time I would be using it to bike to school. For the amount of times I actually go mountain biking, I can just change the tires each time. I was wondering if I would be able to put hybrid tires on this bike. Also, don’t ask why or judge, but would I also be able to put 26” wheels on the small size frame?

Comment: Yes, it will run hybrid tires and you can fit 26" wheels as it has disk brakes.  The Chameleon is a very nice and expensive bike, if you do not have very secure storage at school, I recommend thinking about a second, cheaper bike for school, more suited to commuting.

Comment: 26" wheels on a small makes it sound like this bike might be too big for you -- its not always the case that simply dropping the height a bit is sufficient for good riding. Also, that's a crazy expensive commuter.

Comment: You need a hack commuter bike for school.  A rigid MTB with smoothish tyres, and fenders to keep you cleaner.     Not an nice expensive squishy MTB  - else you will be the nice bike that gets stolen.   Don't risk your nice ride at school.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 'hybrid tire' you mean a wide slick or semi-slick suitable for street use. You can fit any tire that is not too narrow for the rim, and not so large it interferes with the frame. The rims are 40mm so anything above 1.75" will work (although putting a narrow tire on this bike is not necessarily recommended). The stock tires are 3" but you would not want to go above that for street use.

As the bike has disc brakes you can swap the wheels out for smaller diameter ones. Going to ISO 599 rims will drop the bike 12.5mm *in addition* to whatever effective wheel diameter reduction you get by fitting smaller width tires.

I won't question why you want 26" wheels, but I will question why you'd buy a new bike then swap out a expensive major component ... err, well, I guess 26" wheel XC mountain bikes are not really available any more, but then have to consider if you'll have a hard time finding 26" disc brake MTB wheels (unless you wanna have a set built of course).